# Length of array Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm importing a .csv file into matlab. The file has 5 columns, I want to get the length of the 3rd column, ie the middle one.

I've tried `length(B,3)` where B is the file.

`B = importdata(fileName,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);`

I can't get it to work as it returns 1 everytime.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the size of the third column can be obtained by

```
size( B( :, 3 ) )
```

However, size `B` is a matrix all columns must have the same size!
So, you may just as well type

```
size( B, 1 )
```

To get the number of rows in matrix `B`

Comment: `elements = size( B( :,3 ) );` thats what I have in my code right now and its giving me a error. But it doesn't say what the error is.

Comment: @ELSheepO (1) I find it difficult to believe "it doesn't say what error": please try and see what it does say. use [`lasterror`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterror.html) if you have to.   (2) can you please check the type of `B`? type `class(B)`. Is it `cell` or `double` ?

Comment: last error
??? Undefined function or method 'last' for input arguments of type 'char'. Thats the info it gives me
 
>> class(B)

ans =

struct

Comment: @ELSheepO (1) `lasterror` is written as a single word.  (2) if `B` is a struct, please check what are its fields (using `fieldnames`, or just by typing `B` in the command line). Then it would seems like you are interested in the size of one of `B`'s fields.

Comment: Last error gives me `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` typing B in the command line gives:  data: [2475x5 double]
      textdata: {'X Value'  ' Y Value'  ' Z Value'  ' Long'  ' Lat '}
    colheaders: {'X Value'  ' Y Value'  ' Z Value'  ' Long'  ' Lat '}  I am interested in the size of the Z value column

Comment: importing data from file with header lines returns all the data in `B`. So the size of your data matrix is `size( B.data )` which has `2475` rows and `5` columns.

Comment: how would I get just the size of 1 column, or seperate the rows out of that? As the number of rows will be changing.

Comment: @ELSheepO `size( B.data(:,3) )`

Comment: Thanks, I had the , in the wrong place when i was trying it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

csv files are normally imported by csvread function i.e.:

```
B = csvread(fileName);
```

This however will give you a matrix, so all columns would be of the same lengths. Indeed, by definition ([rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)):

> Each line should contain the same number of fields throughout the file